# ASP.NET UserControl inheritance - get derived class control from base

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, webforms, user-controls

I have several user controls that derive from `BaseCtrl`.

`BaseCtrl` does not have an `.ascx` markup page, but only a code definition in a `.cs` file.

I'm sure that all the controls that explicitly derive from `BaseCtrl` have a `ChildControl` instance with ID `CC` defined in their `.ascx` markup page.

I need to retrieve the `CC` instance present in the derived control from the `BaseCtrl` code.

---

Derived1.ascx

```
...
<uc1:ChildControl runat="server" ID="CC" />
...
```

---

Derived1.ascx.cs

```
public class Derived1 : BaseCtrl { ... }
```

---

Derived2.ascx

```
...
<uc1:ChildControl runat="server" ID="CC" />
...
```

---

Derived2.ascx.cs

```
public class Derived2 : BaseCtrl { ... }
```

---

BaseCtrl.cs

```
public class BaseCtrl : UserControl
{
    protected ChildControl DerivedCC
    {
        get { /* ??? */ }
    };
}
```

How can I get the derived class's child control instance in the `DerivedCC` property of the `BaseCtrl`?

Is it possible to get it at any time during the page life cycle, or does the derived control need to be fully loaded/initialized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use the [FindControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) method to find the `CC` child control by its ID:

```
public class BaseCtrl : UserControl
{   
    protected ChildControl DerivedCC
    {
        get { return (ChildControl)this.FindControl("CC"); }
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** Add a protected field named `CC` to `BaseCtrl`, and remove the auto-generated `CC` field from the designer file of each derived user control:

```
public class BaseCtrl : UserControl
{   
    protected ChildControl CC;

    protected ChildControl DerivedCC
    {
        get { return this.CC; }
    }
}
```

(Of course, you may want to remove the `DerivedCC` property altogether since it's redundant.)

**Option 3:** Make `DerivedCC` an abstract property in `BaseCtrl` and override it in each derived user control:

```
public abstract class BaseCtrl : UserControl
{
    protected abstract ChildControl DerivedCC { get; }
}

public class Derived1 : BaseCtrl
{
    protected override ChildControl DerivedCC
    {
        get { return this.CC; }
    }
}

// And similarly for Derived2.
```

All three options allow you to access `DerivedCC` at any point in the page life cycle, except in the controls' constructors (at which point the property will return null).

Option 1 has the advantage that it requires the least amount of code changes from what you currently have.

Option 2 has the advantage that it's arguably simpler and cleaner than calling FindControl.

Option 3 has the advantage that it helps verify *at compile time* that you actually have a `CC` child control in each derived user control.

Comment: option 1 : be aware that Findcontrol is not recursive. ie. if the direct parent  control of DerivedCC is not BaseCtrl, FindControl will return null.

Comment: @Bombinosh: FindControl *is* recursive -- just not through naming containers. Thus FindControl will find CC if it's contained within a Panel or PlaceHolder, but not if it's contained within a Repeater, UserControl, or anything else that implements INamingContainer.

Comment: True. I forgot that i was mainly working with templated controls, hence the need for the recursive implementation of findcontrol. Anyway it's good for the OP to know about the INamingContainer restriction